Raw payload of a packet change while passing through a gre tunnel
I have to tag a packet using the personal id of the sender, and in order to do that I'm encapsulating it in a gre packet. I'm using an hash function on the id and then:
gre_packet = Ether() / IP(src=packet[IP].src, dst=packet[IP].dst) / GRE() / Raw(load=hash_value) / packet[IP].payload

When i get the packet in the second VM and i try to retrieve the tag, whatever was the original hash_value, i find
digest = packet.getlayer(Raw).load
print(digest)
"b',-./012345"

The tunnel between the VMs is a gre tunnel that i created ad hoc for that and i can't figure out where is the problem. Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance for the help.
